# fade/show UIButton when scroll down/up

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton, scrollview

I have a tableView. on view is UIButton. i want when scroll down button fade and when scroll stop or up button show.

[image]

code:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
NSLog(@"Start scroll");

//I assume the buttons are within your cells so you will have to enable them within your cells so you will probably have to handle this by sending a custom message to your cells or accessing them with properties.
CGRect frame = addCommentBtn.frame;
frame.origin.y = scrollView.contentOffset.y + self.newsTableView.frame.size.height  + 4;
addCommentBtn.frame = frame;

[self.view bringSubviewToFront:addCommentBtn];}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
NSLog(@"End scroll");

// do the same to enable them back
CGRect frame = addCommentBtn.frame;
frame.origin.y = scrollView.contentOffset.y + self.newsTableView.frame.size.height  + 4;
addCommentBtn.frame = frame;

[self.view bringSubviewToFront:addCommentBtn];}
```

but don't work correctly!
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong method. Instead of
`scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:` use `scrollViewDidScroll:` and update button alpha and position based on `contentOffset` of the scroll view.